# Show div outside its overflow hidden parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with overflow hidden and an element inside which is a select made with li's with absolute position but it is too long for the parent container, so I want this element to  go out of the container, but the overflow hidden (the parent container has many other elements and it has horizontal scroll) doesn't allow this one to go out.

Below is the screenshot of this:

[image]

Comment: Add fiddle with specific details

Comment: that's what `overflow: hidden` is for

Comment: Which browser are you using, and which version?

Answer (score 0):

Set the width (not "auto") to your child container

```
<div id="pCont" style="overflow:auto; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
   <div id="cCont" style="overflow:hidden; width: 200px;">
      <ul>
          <li>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the expected behavior for an absolute positioned child of an element whose overflow is hidden. The only way around this is to make your fake select box dropdown a child of the `<body>` element, and position it by the fake select box, which breaks some of the HTML semantics.

The bigger question is, why do you need the overflow hidden to begin with? If removing `overflow: hidden` on the parent breaks something, that becomes the problem to solve. Otherwise, the answer to your current question is:

> Overflow and absolute positioning is behaving as designed